# Is it possible to display animated gif in jetpack?

Tags: user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen, gif

I'm trying to implement  a gif in my splash screen using jetpack.Tried this one as suggested but no output .What am I missing?

val context = LocalContext.current

```
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
    .componentRegistry {
        if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
            add(ImageDecoderDecoder(context))
        } else {
            add(GifDecoder())
        }
    }
    .build()


Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        imageLoader = imageLoader,
        data = R.id.mygif,
        builder = {
            size(OriginalSize)
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 100.dp)
)
```

Comment: Coil Compose apparently supports this. See https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/discussions/1051

Comment: Thanks I tried this but nothing is being displayed :((

Comment: And for some reason "it" is unresolved

Comment: Post minimum reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: done I have edited og post

Comment: It worked.Turns out i gave the drawable id wrong

Comment: is there a way to adjust the size of the gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Compose is not supporting gif out of the box, I could not find any reference to gif files in the docs. However, one of the popular library out there to deal with gifs is **Coil**.

-> Here is coil for Compose:
https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/

-> Make sure to add the gif extension:
https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/gifs/

-> You will have to override the ImageLoader and add the gif extension:
https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#localimageloader

Answer (score 2):

For those, who is still looking for answer, here is updated version (since LocalImageLoader is deprecated) in [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/).

Same steps for installation:

- Add implementation for [coil-compose](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/)
- Add implementation for [coil-gif](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/gifs/)

Usage:

```kt
@Composable
fun Content() {
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .components {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder.Factory())
            }
        }
        .build()

    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(data = R.drawable.mettaton_battle_box)
                .apply(block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                    size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                }).build(),
            imageLoader = imageLoader
        ),
        contentDescription = null,
    )
}
```