# Load GIF from URL in Jetpack Compose using Coil

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, gif, coil

I want to show GIFs from URLs in my Jetpack Compose app. From what I can see, Coil is the only way to do it currently.
It seems that the `ImageRequest.Builder(context).data()` method accepts the `httpUrl` data type, however, I have not gotten it to work.
Is it even possible? If not, is there any other way to do it? I am new to Compose so this might have a simple solution.

I used this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138477/is-it-possible-to-display-animated-gif-in-jetpack](https://stackoverflow.com) for the image builder. I am not getting any errors but the grid is not showing up. I also tried a very simple implementation of AsyncImage() but that did not work either.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun GifGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    gifList: List<GiphyItem>
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .components {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder.Factory())
            }
        }
        .build()

    LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
        columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(3),
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalItemSpacing = 12.dp,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp),
        content = {
            items(gifList) { item ->
                Image(
                    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                        ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(item.url.toHttpUrl()).apply(block = {
                            size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                        }).build(), imageLoader = imageLoader
                    ),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.clip(
                        RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

GiphyItem data class:

```
data class GiphyItem(
    val id: String = "",
    val url: String = ""
)
```

Comment: Is your problem with downloading the image, or with displaying an animated GIF?

Comment: Displaying an animated GIF. Images from drawables work fine. I would prefer to load them in from a URL but if that is not possible, downloading them into a variable first could work as well. Got any ideas?

Comment: I still don't see how the way you download them makes a difference. Does the animated GIF work if you load it from a drawable resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who might be lost, my issue was not at all with the composable itself. It was the url from Giphy I was using,- **AsyncImage only renders GIFs whose urls end with `.gif`**. Rookie mistake. :D
I needed to dig deeper into the GIF Object of the Giphy API.
Also, here is the composable grid I ended up using:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun GifGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    gifList: List<GiphyItem>
) {
    LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
        columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(3),
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalItemSpacing = 12.dp,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp),
        content = {
            items(gifList, key = { it.id }) { item ->
                AsyncImage(
                    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                        .data(item.images.downsized.url)
                        .decoderFactory(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
                        .build(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this code to display an image from a URL:

```
val image = remember { myImageUrl.openStream().use { loadImageBitmap(it) } }
Image(image, "my image")
```

I haven't tested it with animated GIFs, so try and see.